# What is the role Overlay in OpenLayers?

Tags: openlayers

What is the role Overlay in OpenLayers?
I saw OpenLayers docs and example, but I can't understand Overlay's role.
Overlay example in Openlayers docs has only pop-up.
I want to know what is overlay's real role, eg) Can I use overlay like ImageLayer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you are confuse, Overlays are widgets or components. There are like Controls, but the difference with Controls is that they are tied to a geographical point not to a position in the screen. For example, the overview map is a Control and is fixed to a position in the screen, usually a corner over the map. The overlays are for example markers or labels, that is, objects that display over the map and tied to a geographical position.

[OL Overlay API Doc](https://openlayers.org/en/latest/apidoc/module-ol_Overlay-Overlay.html)

[OL Control API DOC](https://openlayers.org/en/latest/apidoc/module-ol_control_Control-Control.html)

Comment: OK, I know what's the role overlay now. But I have another question. What is Overlay and ImageLayer difference? somebody use satellite image with overlay, But I think that image use ImageLayer...

Comment: You should use ImageLayer to load images. I am not sure how you could do it with an overlay, maybe there is a way. What I am pretty sure is that the purpose of the overlays is not loading images as a layer.